# Не могу сделать запись в базу данных MySQL, используя уникальный индекс

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица, у которой есть следующие колонки: receiver_id , author_id , article_id и liked. Колонки id нету.
Стоит следующий уникальный индекс: receiver_id, author_id, article_id, liked.

Когда я делаю такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO likes (receiver_id, author_id, article_id, liked) VALUES (412, 13, 23, 1)
```

то запрос проходит. Но когда я делаю такой же, только меняю article_id, то запрос не проходит:

```
INSERT INTO likes (receiver_id, author_id, article_id, liked) VALUES (412, 13, 24, 1)
```

Почему? При изменении article_id индекс получается уникальным в любом случае

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку. Не обратил внимание что `receiver_id` является PRIMARY KEY, поэтому выдается ошибка 1062.